# AWS S3 - createPresignedPost not working. Need an example

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

`createPresignedPost()` function is not working for me and it's very hard to determine what part of my code is wrong since the error doesn't state it explicitly.

```js
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { createPresignedPost } from "@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post";
import { env } from "@/env/server.mjs";

// Instantiating the client
const accessKeyId = env.AWS_S3_ACCESS_KEY;
const secretAccessKey = env.AWS_S3_SECRET_KEY;
const client = new S3Client({
    region: "us-east-1",
    credentials: { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey },
});

// Defining variables
const Bucket = "my-unique-awsbucket";
const Key = "user/" + 123 + "/avatar";
const Fields = {
    acl: "public-read",
    key: Key,
};

// Getting the presignedPost info
const { url, fields } = await createPresignedPost(client, {
    Bucket,
    Key,
    Fields,
    Expires: 600, // Expires in 10 minutes
    });
```

These are the fields I get in return

```js
{
  url: "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-unique-awsbucket",
  fields: {
  acl: 'public-read',
  key: 'user/123/avatar',
  bucket: 'my-unique-awsbucket',
  'X-Amz-Algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
  'X-Amz-Credential': '<IAM_user_id>/20221015/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request',
  'X-Amz-Date': '20221015T170146Z',
  Policy: 'hidden',
  'X-Amz-Signature': 'hidden'
  }
}
```

My code to post to s3

```js
import FormData from "form-data";

const form = new FormData();
Object.entries(fields).forEach(([field, value]) => {
    form.append(field, value);
});

const imagepath = path.join(process.cwd(), "mountains.jpg");
const img = fs.readFileSync(imagepath); // <- Also tried a readstream but no difference
form.append("file", img);

// As per docs
form.submit(url, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("form.submit: err", err);
    }
    console.log("Done.")
});
```

[AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/interfaces/_aws_sdk_s3_presigned_post.presignedpost-1.html) \

The error I get is different depending on what I try.

1. If I try it with Postman, I get XML saying `Access Denied`
2. If I try it with axios, I get... `MissingContentLength - You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header`... When I add that header and the size of the file, it says `AccessControlListNotSupported - The bucket does not allow ACLs`. I remove the acl key under `Fields` and then it errors with `MalformedPOSTRequest - The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data`.
3. When I try it with `form.submit` as per above... it doesn't even show an error, but no image shows up in the bucket.
4. What's even more weird, is when I put a random and incorrect `secretAccessKey`, it still spits out a `url` and `field` parameter, so it's hard to narrow down if the IAM is wrong, or my posting method, or the headers, or the file type...

[AWS-IAM]: My IAM User only allows `PutObject` access level for the user. I think this is enough permissions? I don't see a `PostObject` permission, so I think Put is sufficient, or maybe I gave the wrong permissions cuz I'm POSTing and not PUTing?

My bucket policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "hidden",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-unique-awsbucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

My CORS policy

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "HEAD",
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Does anyone have a clear example how to upload to this presigned URL?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up working for me. Notably:

- Didn't include any acl policies
- STILL couldn't get axios to work. Used formData submit.

```js
import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { createPresignedPost } from "@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import FormData from "form-data";

const getPresignedPostUrl = async ({ id }) => {
    // Instantiating the client
    const client = new S3Client({
        region: "us-east-1",
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: <enter-access-key-id>,
            secretAccessKey: <enter-secret-access-key>,
        },
    });

    const filename = "mountains.jpg";

    // Creating the presignedPostUrl 
    const { url, fields } = await createPresignedPost(client, {
        Bucket: "my-unqiue-awsbucket",
        Key: `user/${id}/${filename}`,
        Conditions: [
            { bucket: "my-unqiue-awsbucket" },
            ["starts-with", "$key", `user/${id}`],
            ["content-length-range", 0, 1000000],
        ],
        Fields: {
            key: `user/${id}/${filename}`,
        },
        Expires: 600, // Expires in 10 minutes
    });

    // Filling in the form data with the `form-data` package 
    const formData = new FormData();
    Object.entries(fields).map(([key, value]) => {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });
    const imgpath = path.join(process.cwd(), filename);
    const file = fs.readFileSync(imgpath, "utf-8");
    formData.append("file", file);

    // POSTing the form to aws
    formData.submit(url, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("form.submit: err", err.response.data);
        }
        console.log("Done.", res.response);
    });
};
```

Amendment: Tried this library called `ky-universal` or `ky` when using the browser, and wow, it just works and a lot less code than axios. The relevant POSTing to AWS S3 is below.

Amendment2: The `got` package also works really well. Just replace `ky` with got, same syntax - very easy and much less code. Apparently it's made by the same people, `ky` for browser, `got` for nodejs/server-side requests.

```js
import ky from 'ky-universal';

const response = await ky.post(url, {
    body: formData
});
```